# How to give input values from user to a process run in a program

Tags: c

I am running a process in my c program. I need to give parameter from the user to this process before it starts running.How can i do it?

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
char inp[10];
printf("\nInput the interface\n");
scanf("%s",inp);
system("ifconfig [interface from user(inp)]"); //interface from user
}
```

I need 8th line to be like

```
system("ifconfig eth0"); //if user want eth0 interface
```

Comment: So what's wrong with [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

Comment: sorry i don't know what snprintf is, can you elaborate?

Comment: How about [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)? The `snprintf` is just a safer version of `sprintf`. Oh, and follow the links, the reference should be enough.

Comment: I cannot find the connection between my question and what you suggested, i think i am new to this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do e.g.

```
char buffer[256];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "ifconfig %s", inp);

system(buffer);
```

If you're on Windows, use `_snprintf` instead.

Comment: Thanks now i got it, i wasn't aware of the fact that we can use array name in system() as a parameter and specify the process.

Comment: @DDR A string is a string is a string... :)